# Running application containing a SQLCE db causes "Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region." on windows 7

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce, installshield

I have just finished developing a wpf application that uses a sql ce db. I am using installshield2010 express to package up the application.
I have created a folder (ProgramData) within installshield and created a directoy for my db e.g. c:\ProgramData\Test\Data\MyDb.sdf however when I run the application I get an error 
Internal error: Cannot open the shared memory region.

If I run the application as an administrator everything is ok however I want anyone to be able to run the application, without admin rights.

What do I need to do??

Comment: you need to post more details. Try investigating the Windows error log for more details. Right click My computer, Manage, open up Computer management, Event Viewer> Windows Log > application and find the errror there and then paste the details..... btw does your installer install the SQLCE runtimes?

Answer (score 1):

CommonAppDataFolder ( C:\ProgramData on some OS's ) doesn't give all users write permissions by default.  You may have to open it up or redesign your application to account for this.